# algorithm to compare the number in the map value and return key

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a map map<integer,float> grades = new map<integer,float>()
This map contains the key and value. like this

{1=140.035000, 2=119.035000, 3=87.535000, 4=79.485000, 5=77.385000, 6=52.535000, 7=0.0000}

I need a logic like this. based on input I want compare the value where it lies in between and return key of that map.

example : if input is 90. i want check where the number lies and return (key) 3 and if number is 79.485 i want to return 4 as a answer so on. I need to compare between the two values of map and return the lowest key of the map if the input number lies between them.

[Map table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpehQ.jpg)

Comment: "I want compare the value where it lies in between and return key of that value." => I don't get the point with your example: "if number is (value) 90 i want to return (key) 3"
90 lies in between 87.535000 and... ?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to make sure your map is a [NavigableMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html) and  check which ones of `ceilingEntry`, `floorEntry`, `higherEntry` and `lowerEntry` is the most suited for your need